# Android Button onTouch(), if return true, has no click animation effect; if return false, has clik animation effect

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I observe this weird behavior, please help me figure it out!

I simply set a onTouchListner to a button. For the `onTouch()` callback, if I set it return false, when I click on the button, I can see the click animation effect of the button (simply color change); However, if I set it return true, when I click on the button, the click animation effect just disappeared.

Below is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.setClickable(true);
                Log.d("myTrack", "onTouch");
                return true;  // I cannot see the animation effect when click
                return false; // I can see the animation effect when click
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I observe this weird behavior, please help me figure it out!

This is default behaviour of Android.

If you return `true` from an `ACTION_DOWN` event you are interested in the rest of the events in that gesture. A "gesture" in this case means all events until the final `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL`. Returning `false` from an `ACTION_DOWN` means you do not want the event and other views will have the opportunity to handle it. If you have overlapping views this can be a sibling view. If not it will bubble up to the parent.

So when you return `true`, you have told android that you have handled all events, and it has nothing to do with. So you don't see any ripple effects even.

Comment: Is there any to edit this default behavior? like manually add ripple effect while still returning true?

Comment: Tell me your requirement, so i can tell you best solution.

Comment: Ok, the whole story is: I have a onClickListener() and onTouchListener() on the same view. I want `onClick` to handle single click, and `onTouch` with `GestureDetector` to handle doubleTap.  I don't want to fire `onClick` when I double tap, that's why I want my `onTouch()` callback to return true, indicating that this event has been consumed, so it won't be passed to onClick. But I also don't want to lose the ripple effect by returning true

Comment: Is moving all code from `onClick` to `onSingleTapConfirmed` under `onTouchListener` and abandon `onClickListener` the only way to handle this?

Comment: Do these questions help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14724234/6891563 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13324574/6891563